# Are [tag:tiling] and [tag:tessellation] the same?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Do [tiling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling) and [tessellation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tessellation) denote the same concept? If so, they should be merged.